# Azure DevOps rename classifications

Tags: azure, azure-devops

The classification box in feature view has default values as architecture and business. Is it possible to change those? how?

Comment: You might be able to do so if you [Create and manage inherited processes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/manage-process?view=azure-devops&tabs=new-nav#Createaninheritedprocess)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of today, a lot of the system provided fields can not be customized in the inherited process model.  Ability to modify the system values is flagged to be on the roadmap though, so you might add your use-case onto the developercommunity's [feature request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365553/vsts-custom-team-capacity-activity-as-well-as-cust.html).

That being said, there is nothing stopping you from creating a similar custom field named similarly and hiding the system field.

Comment: Somehow I find it weird that tool for developers is not highly customizable. However, thanks for the idea to circumvent this problem.